# How to store floating point numbers from FPU to memory?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att, x87

I want to create a program that prints out the cosine of a number using printf.
However, for that I need to move the result of fcos to %xmm0.
I tried to use memory as an intermediate step, but I get an "operand type mismatch for `fstp'" error.

```
.data
    result: .double 1.56098098

[...]

    fldl result
    fcos
    fstp $result
```

Comment: You do not move floats into `rsi`. The sysv convention uses `xmm0` for the first float (double). The error is due to the `$` sign. Also you should type out `fstpl` to make sure it's a double.

Comment: @Jester you're right. How can I move it into xmm0, tho?

Comment: Once you have gotten it back into the `result` you can `movss` it.

Comment: How do I get it back into result, if I get the error?

Comment: Told you the problem is the `$`. You want `fstpl result`.

Comment: Thank you it worked. Why was it an issue though? I thought that $ was for addressing, while a label itself is just the value

Comment: The `$` is for selecting an instruction that takes an immediate.